Are these stars or noise around Saturn?
This is a pic of Saturn taken last night and i see lot of stars though only 1 or 2 were visible in raw photo hence confused if it is just noise as i have boosted whites and exposure a lot. No stacking done just a single shot hence more confused.
Taken with a D3500 | 150-600mm Tamron G2 lens
600mm |
400 ISO |
F8


It's always a good idea to take multiple frames when you have the setup running -- with that, you could check if the same (or slightly offset by planetary motion) pattern appears around the true target...

What were your exposure settings? Particularly how long was the exposure time? Where you using any kind of tracking mount?

Please open up https://stellarium-web.org/ and dial in Saturn as target and set the exact date when you took the picture. You should be able identify Saturn's moons in your picture. These are brighter than the stars, as they are reflecting sunlight as Saturn does.

Yes.
That is to say, there is almost certainly some of both in your image. After all, there are more dim stars in the sky than bright ones. The brighter we expose, the more stars will show up. Likewise, the brighter we amplify what our sensor captures, the more stars will show up. But noise will also be amplified by the same amount.
If you really stop and think about it: no matter what your exposure is, there will always be some (hopefully very dim) stars that are the same brightness as the read noise in your image. Unless you intentionally take a frame with camera motion or slight focus blur, so that the stars are blurred but the noise will continue to be sharp points, it's pretty hard to tell the difference. Defocusing only works so far, though, because if you defocus too much you just spread the light from the dimmest stars you capture at a particular exposure level so much that they do not register at all. Long enough exposure without any tracking movements never lies. If the stars are streaks, they're not noise. If the stars are streaked, anything that is still a point is noise.

They are too bright to be stars
Unless you have separately adjusted the brightness of the background stars and the planet, the exposure doesn't make sense.
Saturn is a relatively bright object at 1.0 apparent magnitude currently, has area of 150 pixels in your image and sRGB brightness of 70%. The size of the image is about 15x27 arc minutes, or 0.25x0.45 degrees.
There are 176 "stars" that have saturated to fully white color. For them to saturate, their apparent magnitude would have to be brighter than 6. (Estimated from pixel brightness ratio (1.0/0.7)sRGB_gamma, area ratio 1 / 150 and magnitude difference log(1 / 150 * 2.2) / log(2.51) = -4.6.)
Random area of the sky with area of 0.1 square degrees can be expected to contain 0.05 stars of magnitude 6 or brighter.
I would rule these as noise. Even at magnitude 10, the pictured area would contain at most a couple of stars.
If the background and planet brightnesses have been separately adjusted, it is borderline possible that a good telescope and camera setup could photograph magnitude 14 stars (expected count ~150) without overexposing saturn.

You can compare the dots right around Saturn with a star chart program like Stellarium to see if they map to stars. You'll need to set the program to the date the image was taken for the comparison. Otherwise, I agree with Michael's answer.

They are stars; at least primarily.
For one thing I do not see the chroma noise that would generally be associated with severe image recovery. I.e. one would expect the colors of the noise to be related to the RGB color filter array due to a lack of information. I.e. typically red or blue, sometimes all three colors, and sometimes a combination of two colors (i.e. magenta).
Secondly, they appear to pixel groups and not individual pixels. I.e. they are demosaiced details and not pixel noise.
It is possible that a few of them are hot(stuck) pixels, or even hot pixels affecting surrounding pixels (bloom). However photosite bloom was/is more common with CCD, and it is not common in CMOS sensors. Even if it does occur on a CMOS sensor it has a strong RGB correlation (i.e. red) due to the hot pixel's overwhelming dominance. And it is unlikely that there is more than a few stuck pixels that would show.
It should be easy enough to determine if you disable any noise reduction. This is a crappy picture of the moon I took several years ago (not sure why I still had it), and there are some stars visible around it.

This is the same image recovered 4 stops without any noise reduction. There are now additional stars visible, but they are easily distinguishable from the image/sensor noise. The noise characteristic is much finer and retains more RGB separation/distinction than the demosaiced stars do.


Hot pixels very often do create a multi pixel pattern. The hot pixel itself will be the most intense, the four pixels above, below, and to each side will be dimmer, and then the four pixels to the upper left, upper right, lower left, and lower right will be even dimmer. Looks kind of like a step pyramid viewed from directly overhead. It probably depends, to one degree or another, on exactly what the demosaicing algorithm does.

@MichaelC, I'll add to my answer

I think the post processing may have upped brightness so much that the pixels have saturated to white. Otherwise it would seem a bit weird to have Saturn in good exposure and so many stars saturated to fully white.

@jpa the smaller the area is, the more likely it is that color noise reduction will neutralize it.
